How to get bkchem structure drawing software working on Ubuntu 24.04
Two fellow chemists trusted me with their laptops to install Ubuntu 24.04 to dual-boot with Windows or MacOS. Then we wanted software to draw organic chemical structures, and the most familiar option to me was bkchem.
The install was easy from the command line, and no dependencies were installed:
sudo apt-get install bkchem
But the program wouldn't launch from the desktop. Running it from the command line gave:

b'UNABLE TO IMPORT PMW\n\nSorry, but BKChem relies too heavily on Pmw
to be usable without it. Please install Pmw and try again.\n(for more
info on Pmw see documentation)'

How can bkchem be made to work?

I figured out to install pmw with:
sudo apt-get install python3-pmw
but then bkchem complained of a missing module named 'imp'. Apparently, 'imp' has been replaced with 'importlib', and is no longer available as of python version 3.12. Replacing the two offending instances of 'imp' on lines 490 and 504 of the affected code allowed bkchem to launch. A command to begin that edit is:
sudo pico /usr/share/bkchem/bkchem/main.py
I hope that bkchem can continue to be maintained, as it is one of few options for Linux using chemists to draw structures.

When I tried to install bkchem on my own computer, bkchem gave the usual error, but apt-get could no candidate for python3-pmw to install. But my computer is still running Ubuntu 22.04.
